# @Query match _all function

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am new to spring data elasticsearch ,I want to impl this rest query

```
GET _search
{"query": {

"match": {
  "_all": "...myquerystring..."
}
}
}
```

@Query annotation  write like this:

```
@Query("{\"match\":{\"_all\":\"?0\"}}")
```

then I donn't know how to write query function

eg:

```
 @Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : {\"term\" : {\"message\" : \"?0\"}}}}")
    Page<Book> findByMessage(String message, Pageable pageable);
```

how I write find function  for _all query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try like this , @query annotation is not compulsory :-

> With Query :-

```
   @Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : [ {\"match\" : {\"?0\" : \"?1\"}} ]}}")
Page<MyDoc> getbyAll(String a, String b, Pageable pageable);

int aPageReuestcount = (int) myRepositiry.count();
Page<MyDoc> aData = myRepositiry.getbyAll("_all", "HelloWorld", new PageRequest(0, aPageReuestcount));
List<MyDoc> aDataList = aData.getContent();
```

> Without Query :-

```
 @Override
    public List<MyDoc> getDatawithAllFields(String a) {
        NativeSearchQueryBuilder aNativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
        aNativeSearchQueryBuilder.withIndices(indexName).withTypes(type);
        final BoolQueryBuilder aQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        aQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("_all",  a));


        NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = aNativeSearchQueryBuilder.withQuery(aQuery).build();
        List<MyDoc> aData = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(nativeSearchQuery, MyDoc.class);
        return aData;

    }
```

Imports :-

```
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
```

follow this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/) .

Comment: i am afraid  you not understand me, I want to impl GET _search
{"query": {

"match": {
  "_all": "...myquerystring..."
}
}
}    how I write  Repository function  , may not use @Query , _all how to express

Comment: u want to search all data with all fields , than go with myRepository.findAll() . findAll() is default method ElasticsearchRepository .

Comment: not exactly, I mean GET _search
{"query": {

"match": {
  "_all": "...myquerystring..."
}
}
}  I  can specifiy query string ...myquerystring...   myRepository.findAll(querystring) cannot work.
I want search    all data satisfied  specified query with all field

Comment: Looking forward to your answer, I am online

Comment: thank you very much , I follow you method ,and it work fine, I am new to elasticsearch  so I am not familiar with
 NativeSearchQueryBuilder  ,then I will learn it soon ,
Thanks again, best wishes for you

Comment: Now I have implemented with @query also . Making your solution more smart .